# changing display name on smtp with hotmail mail don't work c#

Tags: c#, smtp

I want to change display name from my username to custom name when sending email in this case i'am using hotmail as my mail, as you can see there i want to change to "my company" custom display name, it success to send message but the display still using default name not my custom name.

Before doing above i'm using gmail as my mail it work well i can send email and my display name change to my wanted name.

Any problem with my code?

```
    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
    var mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("youremail@hotmail.com","My Company");
    mail.To.Add("to@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Test Mail - 1";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    string htmlBody;
    htmlBody = "Write some HTML code here";
    mail.Body = htmlBody;
    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("youremail@hotmail.com", "password");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hotmail SMTP server may be ignoring the value you use for the name in the From field and is instead using the name your account settings (“default” name). Servers frequently do this to prevent a kind of spoofing of the sender.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was the parsing on the email body from hotmail. Can you try enclosing the custom name to @"\My Company\"

Comment: i have tried but it does not work, How about you have you tried ?